# Alsamixer - What are these numbers beside the controls

Tags: sound, alsa

I'm new to Ubuntu and want to use Alsamixer, but can't understand what these numbers and how do they change, for example the Master control starts with -94.5 and ends with 0.0, and the PCM starts with -34.5 and ends with 60.0, I know these are decibels but what is the equation they are change, or where to find a documentation about them, I searched in alsamixer docs but found nothing

could anyone please describe about this, Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to show only playback or only capture controls (F3/F4).

dB values are relative; 0 dB means no change in volume.
To understand how the individual controls affect the sound, you would have to know how the sound is routed inside the hardware.

The dB limits are simply reported by the sound driver (or in case of USB, by the device), and there is no information about the routing, so alsamixer cannot help you.

The mixer controls of the CS4297A are shown in its [datasheet](https://www.alsa-project.org/files/pub/datasheets/cirrus/4297a.pdf):

[image: CS4297A mixer]